# connect to jackrabbit from Jahia

Tags: java, repository, jackrabbit, ddd-repositories, jahia

do you know if is it possible to point my Jahia 6.5 installation to an existing Jackrabbit?
I took a look into the configuration files and it seems possible but I don't know how to correctly configure Jahia.

On Jahia configuration there are:

```
######################################################################
### Disk Paths  ######################################################
######################################################################
# The following disk paths configure where Jahia will store data on disk,
# such as temporary files or content files, or even in some cases where
# it will retrieve additional configuration from.

#jahiaFilesDiskPath                                     = $context/WEB-INF
jahiaEtcDiskPath                                       = $context/WEB-INF/etc/
jahiaVarDiskPath                                       = $context/WEB-INF/var/
#tmpContentDiskPath                                     = $context/WEB-INF/var/content/tmp/

jahiaSharedTemplatesDiskPath                           = $context/WEB-INF/var/shared_modules/
jahiaImportsDiskPath                                   = $context/WEB-INF/var/imports/
```

but the repository folder structure is quite difference in my Jackrabbit installation.

Anybody did it?

Cheers,

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discussed with Jahia Support team and no, for the moment it's not possible to connect jahia to another Jackrabbit instance.

thanks,
Andrea